# Blazor server side how to get the value of a clicked element

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I am using Blazor server side and have 3 boxes on my page with a date:

Index.razor

```
<div class="box">
 @DateTime.Now
</div>

<div class="box">
 @DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
</div>

<div class="box">
 @DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)
</div>
```

I need the date of the clicked box for some server logik operations. How can I achieve that 'tracking of the selected item' in a blazor way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
<div id='div0' @onclick='DateCallback(0)'></div>
<div id='div1' @onclick='DateCallback(1)'></div>
<!-- etc... -->

@code {

private readonly DateTime[] dates = new[] { /* fill with date times matching indexes */ };
public void DateCallback(int index)
{
    // make call to server with dates[index]
}

}
```

Whether you store the list of dates in C# code in client or on your server is up to you.

You could also pass strings to the method instead of an int if you like that better.

Comment: what if its an input and we want to get the value from input and send it to that method ?

Comment: @Mamadmti Many answers about that on SO and several possibilities depending on the real needs. Here's the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0) using binding, a simple one.